# Avoiding duplicates in a reflexive many to many relationship where direction is irrelevant

Tags: database, relational-database

Given a table **`users( #user_id )`** and a table **`user_related( #related_user1, #related_user2 )`** where only the existance of a relation between two users is relevant, so if a row as (1, 2) exists in **user_related**, the row (2, 1) would be redundant:

- Thinking in a theoretical, non practical way: is it possible to implement this kind of relationship in a way that no constraint nor check is needed? In a way in which trying to insert a relation between two users when a relationship with swapped IDs already exists violates data integrity?
- Being practical: Which is the best way to implement and query said relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy.  But first, to clear up some misunderstanding that you have.

> Thinking in a theoretical, non practical way: is it possible to implement this kind of relationship in a way that no constraint nor check is needed?

- Theory only has value when it has a practical application (theory that disallows practice, or theory that is divorced from practice, would be invalid, would be pig poop.  Usually called fantasy.
- The theory for Relational databases is Dr E F Codd's *Relational Model*

  - Beware, there are quite a few pretenders, who have weird and wonderful ideas  of what the *Relational Model* is, therefore is it accurate to say, they have their own versions of "relational theory" and "relational".  Probably best to call them Anti-Relational.
- The theory has `CONSTRAINTs`.  Uniqueness is a form of `CONSTRAINT`.  `CHECK` is a form of `CONSTRAINT`.  Without the required `CONSTRAINTS`, the theory would be pig poop.

  - The Anti-Relational theories have a very limited understanding of what is required for databases, and therefore far less `CONSTRAINTS`.

> data integrity

Data integrity is most certainly part of the theory, the *Relational Model*.  Data integrity is the goal, that predicates the need for the various `CONSTRAINTS`.  You simply cannot have data integrity without `CONSTRAINTS`.

> In a way in which trying to insert a relation between two users when a relationship with swapped IDs already exists violates data integrity?

The theory provides for such a constraint, using of course, a `CONSTRAINT`.

> Being practical: Which is the best way to implement and query said relationship?

To be precise, that is not a "relationship", it is a constraint on a relationship.

At the DDL level, you need a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that calls a Function.  That has been an ordinary feature of SQL, the data sublanguage for the *Relational Model*, for many decades.  The Function code is:

```
...
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
        FROM user_related
        WHERE related_user1 = @related_user2
        AND   related_user2 = @related_user1
    )
...
```

- Beware, in the freeware; vapourware; noware category, they use the term SQL, without having the features of SQL.  Their use of the term is fraudulent.  Some do not have `CONSTRAINTS`; some do not have `CHECK` (or worse, allow the keyword but do not perform the check); some don't have Functions; or Functions that can be called from a `CHECK`.

If you need SQL-compliant code examples, please ask.

#### Relational Database

> `users( #user_id )`

That does not give you unique user rows (data).  That gives you unique records in the user file, which is not unique users.  The *Relational Model* is logical, it demands that the Key is made up from the data, as opposed to 1960's Record Filing systems that are promoted by the "theoreticians", which use physical records, not logical rows.

For a Relational database, you need uniqueness on the data that forms the user, a Key such as `user_name`; `social_security_no`; `(name_last, name_first, initial)`, etc.  And then you can get rid of the **record id** `user_id`, because it is redundant and has no purpose.

Starting with an `ID` in every file will guarantee you an Anti-Relational 1960's Record Filing System.  Granted, it is what the "theoreticians" promote.